# How to horizontally align underscore without repeating it?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uilabel

I'm using an underscore character below each form field and related label in my view to logically seperate them. I've added the underscore in a UILabel but I'm looking for a way to repeat the **_** without having to manually type it many times in the text property of the label in IB. Any idea on how to do this ?

I tried checking/unchecking "**adjust to fit**" but it's not working.

Thx for helping

Stephane

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  It sounds like you'd be better served by just putting a box or a line there...

Comment: I'm just trying to add a line below some text fields and their labels.

Comment: I already saw this somewhere in a tutorial but I forgot how they did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is vague question, but if you want a line, I think you should rather insert generic UIView with backgroundColor that imitates the line.

```
UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(linex, liney, thickness, length)];
line.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[view addSubview:line];
[line release];
```

No matter how you'd look at this, this is much better solution than inserting undersocres.

Comment: You may not have understood what I mean. UILabels are definitely better for this and doing it programmatically is not required I think.

Comment: You don't need to do it programmatically if you want a horizontal line. You can do it in the Interface Builder by inserting a _view_ and then adjust its height to some really small value that will imitate the line. After that, adjust background color of that view to your preferred line color.